# Java how to set data in model

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a model below call "TitleModels" which i use to add my data I get from my Api. Unfortunately i am unable to set the data in RatingModels. What is the best way to set data to a model using an array? Unfortunately i get the error "incompatible types: Rating cannot be converted to RatingModels".

The code I am done so far:

```
             import com.alienvers.alienversapp.models.TitleModels;


             private List<TitleModels> inTheaterListMovie = new ArrayList<>();

             //In theater movies data
             for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getInTheaterMovies().size(); i++){
                 InTheaterMovies movie = response.body().getInTheaterMovies().get(i);
                 TitleModels models = new TitleModels();
                 models.setPosterUrl(movie.getPosterUrl());
                 models.setTitle(movie.getTitle());
                 models.setTypeName("movies");
                 models.setReleaseDate(movie.getRelease());
                 models.setPlot(movie.getVideoQuality());
                 models.setId(movie.getVideosId());

                 models.setRatingModels(movie.getRating());



                 inTheaterListMovie.add(models);

             }
```

The error I get:

> error: incompatible types: Rating cannot be converted to RatingModels
>                                models.setRatingModels(movie.getRating());

Model:

```
public class TitleModels {

   public String videosId;
   public String title;
   public String description;
   public String slug;
   public Boolean isPaid;
   public String release;
   public String runtime;
   public String videoQuality;
   public String thumbnailUrl;
   public String posterUrl;
   public RatingModels rating;

   public String getVideosId() {
       return videosId;
   }

   public void setVideosId(String videosId) {
       this.videosId = videosId;
   }

   public String getTitle() {
      return title;
   }

   public void setTitle(String title) {
      this.title = title;
   }

   public String getDescription() {
      return description;
   }

   public void setDescription(String description) {
      this.description = description;
   }

   public String getSlug() {
      return slug;
   }

   public void setSlug(String slug) {
      this.slug = slug;
   }

   public Boolean getIsPaid() {
      return isPaid;
   }

   public void setIsPaid(Boolean isPaid) {
      this.isPaid = isPaid;
   }

   public String getRelease() {
      return release;
   }

   public void setRelease(String release) {
      this.release = release;
   }

   public String getRuntime() {
      return runtime;
   }

   public void setRuntime(String runtime) {
      this.runtime = runtime;
   }

   public String getVideoQuality() {
      return videoQuality;
   }

   public void setVideoQuality(String videoQuality) {
      this.videoQuality = videoQuality;
   }

   public String getThumbnailUrl() {
      return thumbnailUrl;
   }

   public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnailUrl) {
      this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
   }

   public String getPosterUrl() {
      return posterUrl;
   }

   public void setPosterUrl(String posterUrl) {
      this.posterUrl = posterUrl;
   }

   public RatingModels getRating() {
      return rating;
   }

   public void setRating(RatingModels rating) {
      this.rating = rating;
   }

}
```

Here my Rating Model:

```
public class RatingModels {

   public String userRating;
   public String userRatingIcon;
   public String titleRatingCount;
   public String titleRatingScore;

   public String getUserRating() {
      return userRating;
   }

   public void setUserRating(String userRating) {
      this.userRating = userRating;
   }

   public String getUserRatingIcon() {
      return userRatingIcon;
   }

   public void setUserRatingIcon(String userRatingIcon) {
      this.userRatingIcon = userRatingIcon;
   }

   public String getTitleRatingCount() {
      return titleRatingCount;
   }

   public void setTitleRatingCount(String titleRatingCount) {
      this.titleRatingCount = titleRatingCount;
   }

   public String getTitleRatingScore() {
      return titleRatingScore;
   }

   public void setTitleRatingScore(String titleRatingScore) {
      this.titleRatingScore = titleRatingScore;
   }

}
```

Response i get from the server in json format:

```
  "in_theater_movies": [
    {
      "videos_id": "16",
      "title": "Midway",
      "description": "Après la débâcle de Pearl Harbor qui a laissé la flotte américaine dévastée, la marine impériale japonaise prépare une nouvelle attaque qui devrait éliminer définitivement les forces aéronavales restantes de son adversaire.  La campagne du Pacifique va se jouer dans un petit atoll isolé du Pacifique nord : Midway.",
      "slug": "16-midway",
      "is_paid": true,
      "release": "2019",
      "runtime": "138",
      "video_quality": "HD",
      "thumbnail_url": "http://localhost/assets/images/upload/backdrops/1ZSjrBUHP2jm1QlQEyLGufL289q_thumb.jpg",
      "poster_url": "http://localhost/assets/images/upload/posters/pcd4hAysR1RJXlrxplvT5Ag2U1H_thumb.jpg",
      "rating": {
        "user_rating": null,
        "user_rating_icon": null,
        "title_rating_count": "0",
        "title_rating_score": null
      }
    },
    {
      "videos_id": "190",
      "title": "Maléfique : Le Pouvoir du Mal",
      "description": "Plusieurs années après avoir découvert pourquoi la plus célèbre méchante Disney avait un cœur si dur et ce qui l’avait conduit à jeter un terrible sort à la princesse Aurore, Maléfique, le pouvoir du mal, continue d’explorer les relations complexes entre la sorcière et la future reine, alors qu’elles nouent d’autres alliances et affrontent de nouveaux adversaires dans leur combat pour protéger leurs terres et les créatures magiques qui les peuplent.",
      "slug": "190-malefique-le-pouvoir-du-mal",
      "is_paid": true,
      "release": "2019",
      "runtime": "110",
      "video_quality": "HD",
      "thumbnail_url": "http://localhost/assets/images/upload/backdrops/skvI4rYFrKXS73BJxWGH54Omlvv_thumb.jpg",
      "poster_url": "http://localhost/assets/images/upload/posters/eDVBn53859HvDyzVleU4fIvPvcO_thumb.jpg",
      "rating": {
        "user_rating": null,
        "user_rating_icon": null,
        "title_rating_count": "2",
        "title_rating_score": "60.0000"
      }
    },
    {
      "videos_id": "191",
      "title": "Angry Birds : Copains comme cochons",
      "description": "Les oiseaux et les cochons continuent de se battre sans relâche. Mais la menace d’un nouvel adversaire vient perturber les voisins ennemis. Red, Chuck, Bombe et l’Aigle Vaillant recrutent Silver, la sœur de Chuck et s’associent aux cochons Léonard, son assistante Courtney et Garry (le geek), pour former une équipe improbable et tenter de sauver leurs foyers !",
      "slug": "191-angry-birds-copains-comme-cochons",
      "is_paid": true,
      "release": "2019",
      "runtime": "96",
      "video_quality": "HD",
      "thumbnail_url": "http://localhost/assets/images/upload/backdrops/k7sE3loFwuU2mqf7FbZBeE3rjBa_thumb.jpg",
      "poster_url": "http://localhost/assets/images/upload/posters/xNSejOLGZPUjWmBEluklJYoqqOc_thumb.jpg",
      "rating": {
        "user_rating": null,
        "user_rating_icon": null,
        "title_rating_count": "1",
        "title_rating_score": "10.0000"
      }
    },
    {
      "videos_id": "192",
      "title": "Queens",
      "description": "Des stripteaseuses se lient d’amitié et décident de conjuguer leurs talents pour arnaquer et prendre leur revanche sur leurs riches clients de Wall Street.\r\n Leur plan fonctionne à merveille, mais argent et vie facile les poussent à prendre de plus en plus de risques…",
      "slug": "192-queens",
      "is_paid": true,
      "release": "2019",
      "runtime": "107",
      "video_quality": "HD",
      "thumbnail_url": "http://localhost/assets/images/upload/backdrops/5GynP6w2OQWSbKnCLHrBIriF4Cw_thumb.jpg",
      "poster_url": "http://localhost/assets/images/upload/posters/zDkguic7WqrTeLmFGOVQ9OQfdI5_thumb.jpg",
      "rating": {
        "user_rating": null,
        "user_rating_icon": null,
        "title_rating_count": "1",
        "title_rating_score": "50.0000"
      }
    },
  ],
```

Comment: Can you post the  response from the server?

Comment: @emilpmp how can he post the response from the server if his code doesn't even compile?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException so you work without knowing the response from servers? Build models without knowing what the server would respond with? hilarious

Comment: Edited please check, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set `Rating` object to `RatingModels` inside the method `TitleModels` using the set method `setRatingModels` which is not possible.

You have to unpack the `movie.getRating()` and set the attributes to `RatingModels` and then set the object using:

`models.setRatingModels(movie.getRating());`

You can do something like:

```
RatingModels model = new Rating Model();
model.setsetUserRating(movie.getRating().get(i).getUserRating());
.
.
.
```

Then

```
models.setRatingModels(model);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply...How to unpack? I am new in java

Comment: Check ```movie.getRating().``` and check if there are any methods.

Comment: ```movie.getRating()``` place a dot after brackets it will show a list.

Comment: I Tried this but my app crashed models.getRatingModels().setTitleRatingScore(movie.getRating().getTitleRatingScore());

Comment: You do not need to run just check the with the . operator if shows any get method.

Comment: When I want get the data in RatingModels I get an error "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.project.projectapp.models.home_content.RatingModels.getUserRating()' on a null object reference"

Comment: If you create new ```RatingModel ``` object you have to first set and then get. That is why you are getting this error.

Comment: Yes, I set all data but when I want to get them in my adapter i get an error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212703/discussion-between-thenrun-and-mappy-lord).

Answer (score 2):

You have different types

```
models.setRatingModels(movie.getRating());
```

According to `TitleModels` definition:

```
public void setRating(RatingModels rating) {
      this.rating = rating;
}
```

However `InTheaterMovies movie` method `movie.getRating()` return `Rating` and not `RatingModels`. Even if both `InTheaterMovies` and `TitleModels` has field with the same name, type of the filed is different.

```
RatingModels rating;
```

vs

```
Rating rating;
```

I guess you need to update your `jsonParser`, to make sure that `InTheaterMovies raiting` field has type of `RatingModels`.

Or just create a new `RatingModels` from `Rating` object. Something like this:

```
models.setRatingModels(RatingModels.fromRating(movie.getRating()));
```

where `RatingModels.fromRating` is a static factory method:

```
RatingModels Ratring fromRatring(Ratring rating) { 
  RatingModels model = new RatingModels(); 
  model.setUserRating(ratring.getUserRating()); 
  ... // set all reaming properties
  return model;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this using the package 'Gson'. If you are using Android-studio add the respective gradle

Gson gradle

```
compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.3.1'
```

Then create a new model

```
public class TheaterMovies {

@SerializedName("in_theater_movies")
private List<TitleModels> titles;


public List<TitleModels> getTitles() {
    return titles;
}

public void setTitles(List<TitleModels> titles) {
    this.titles = titles;
}}
```

I suppose that the response in Json format that you posted is available from `response.getBody()`

Then do this,

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
TheaterMovies movies = gson.fromJson(response.getBody(), TheaterMovies.class);
```

Tried using the response from your question and is working perfectly. Hope it helps. Happy coding!